# What Model Used for Forecasting Sales with Dynamic Holiday

Tags: neural-networks, linear-regression, forecasting

I'm working on a project where I need to forecast sales data where I have history of 1 year (2017) daily data. I am new on Artificial Intelligence topic and after searching for a while, I think ARIMA or Multiple Linear Regression is a good model for seasonal forecasting (Correct Me If I'm Wrong). But then I think that my history data is exclusive for 2017 because on 2018 and 2019, holiday date is changing.

What model I have to used to forecast based on new holiday setup? Is ARIMA or Multiple Linear Regression still can be used? Or I need another model? Where do I have to start on this?